# Integrate svg-edit in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, svg-edit

I have to integrate [svg-edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) in my rails application. I have downloaded its files but I don't want to separate  all of its css,js and images and place them in app/assets.And give them their respective path.Is there any easy way of integrating it.

I have also seen this gem [sketchily](https://github.com/lml/sketchily) but I need to customize some of the functionalists and It can not be done with this gem.